# Cart total based on product category and items count in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to set the cart total to £10, when there are 4 items in the cart AND none of the items are from the 'christmas' category.

e.g.

- 4 items in cart, but 4 from *christmas* category. Ignore rule and follow per item pricing.
- 4 items in cart, but 4 from *non-christmas* category. Set cart price to £10.
- 4 items in cart, but 2 from *christmas* category. Ignore rule and follow per item pricing.

**I have written code which currently works to set any 4 cart tems to £10:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'calculated_total', 10, 2 );
function calculated_total( $total, $cart ) {
    $taster_item_count = 4;
    if ( $cart->cart_contents_count == $taster_item_count ) {
        return 10;
    }
    return $total;
}
```

**However, when I try to add in the category conditional, it does not follow the rule?:**

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'calculated_total', 10, 2 );

// check each cart item for  category
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    // ONLY EXECUTE BELOW FUNCTION IF DOESN'T CONTAIN CHRISTMAS CATEGORY
    if ( !has_term( 'christmas', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ) {

function calculated_total( $total, $cart ) {
    $taster_item_count = 4;
    if ( $cart->cart_contents_count == $taster_item_count ) {
        return 10;
    }
    return $total;
}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** There are mistakes in your code, try this instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'calculated_total', 10, 2 );
function calculated_total( $total, $cart ) {
    $taster_count = 4;
    $item_count   = $cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $chistm_count = 0;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( ! has_term( 'christmas', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $chistm_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }
    if( $taster_count == $item_count && $chistm_count == $taster_count ) {
        $total = 10;
    }
    return $total;
}
```

It should better work.

Comment: The changes you made, solved point 3 in my question. Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how I could add in a "Free Shipping" to this aswell. So based on conditional being true, offer free shipping? Or is that a separate question...

Comment: @Giuls You can not add Free shipping to a code that is filtering the cart total… That is simply something else that has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Okay understood. What about displaying a "Dummy text" *Free Shipping Applied -£3.00" in the cart totals?

Comment: @Giuls This hook is not for formatted price display, but to alter the price numerically… You should better ask a new question.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528929/woocommerce-format-price-display-of-cart-calculated-fees